# Estimation of program execution time from complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, performance, processing-efficiency

I want to know, **how i can estimate the time that my program will take to execute on my machine** (for example a 2.5 Ghz machine), if i have an estimation of its worst case time complexity?
**For Example** : - If I have a program which is O(n^2), in worst case, and n<100000, how can i know /estimate before writing the actual program/procedure, the time that it will take to execute in seconds?

Wouldn't it be good to know how a program actually performs, and it will also save writing code which eventually turns out to be inefficient!
Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Program performance is an experimental science.  You will/would spend more time devising an accurate prediction for the performance of your program than you would writing your program and timing it.  Then, once you had the accurate prediction you would still have to write the program and test whether or not your predictions fit your observations.  Better to write the program first then test its performance.

Comment: You cannot estimate this before you write it (or at least, before you know what you are going to write).  You need at least one data point first.

Comment: That's like estimating how much gas you need in your tank *before choosing where you want to go*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Suppose i have already proved the correctness of my algorithm, now i want to know how efficient it is, and if not, come up with a better algorithm. I mean, asymptotic time complexities give a bound on the performance, right? I have an algorithm in my mind, and now i want to know it's 'performance' in 'seconds'.

Comment: Actually many coding problems involve 'time limit' (1 sec,2 sec etc) and input constraints. And I have an algorithm, but don't know about its physical running time. That is the motivation of this question.

Comment: You can make a semi-educated guess: `n^2 * (1 / 2.5GHz)`. Just fill in `n` and a mostly useless number rolls out.

Comment: I invite everyone who disagrees with my original comment to post an algorithm which provides an accurate prediction of the running time of a program which has not been written.  No bogus entries please, no programs which sleep for 10 seconds and are predicted to take just a bit longer than 10 seconds to execute, a proper program which, given the specification of a useful `O(n^2)` program, spits out a predicted running time within +/- 10% of the actual running time.

Comment: Let me explain it this way: given an algorithm how will i know before writing the program, whether it will pass the time limit or not?

Comment: There isn't any way to know.  You may need to back up and take another approach if you cannot think of any further local optimizations to your program, it may indicate an error in design (Though this is only a guarantee if you know you should be able to easily clear a certain time and cannot)

Answer (score 4):

Since big O complexity ignores linear coefficients and smaller terms, it is impossible to estimate the performance of an algorithm given only its big o complexity.

In fact, for any specific N, you cannot predict which of two given algorithms will execute faster.

For example, O(N) is not always faster than O(N*N) since an algorithm that takes 100000000*n steps is O(N) is slower than an algorithm than takes N*N steps for many small values of N.

These linear coefficients and asymptotically smaller terms vary from platform to platform and even amongst algorithms of the same equivalence class (in terms of big O measure). 3

**The problem you are trying to use big O notation for is not the one it is designed to solve.**

Comment: Exactly.  You need at least one data point before you can even make a guess as to what the linear coefficients are.

Comment: Yeah, but this is not an abstract setting, OP probably has some idea about the linear coefficients. Please don't tell me You would HAVE to code an O(N^2) algorithm to then discard it when N is 1e5 , an You have 2 seconds to process the data.

Comment: I think that i have realised that big-oh indicates how my processing time will change with variation in input size.For actual time i have to write the code.If it doesn't pass the time limit, it means it has to be optimised further...so its better to write as much optimised code using efficient data structures and algorithms as possible...right guys??

Comment: That's correct.  Optimization is heavily grounded in testing- sadly, the fact that you may be using an inefficient algorithm is one of the things you will have to learn to correct for through research.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with complecity, you might want to have a look at `Worst Case Execution Time` (WCET). This area of research most likely corresponds to what you are looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_execution_time

Comment: I don't think this would be a good approach before an algorithm is written.

Answer (score -1):

Multiply N^2 by the time You spend in an iteration of the innermost loop, and You have a ballpark estimate.

Comment: But this will require OP to write a code, OP explicitly wants to estimate running time before writing code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You can often easily estimate time spent in the innermost loop. Anyway, for O(N^2) with N=100K I wouldn't expect anything less than 10 minutes.